# Querying nested lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes:

```
public GeneralClassName 
{
    public GeneralClassName ()
    {
        SpecificList = new List<OtherClass>();
    }
    public string StringValue;
    public string OtherStringValue;
    public List<OtherClass> SpecificList;
}
```

and

```
public OtherClass
{
    public string Name;
    public string Number;
}
```

After a JSON deserialization I obtain a nice `List<GeneralClassName>`, the result I want is a `Dictionary<string, int>` whose value is the sum of the variabiles "Number" inside `List<OtherClass>` inside `List<GeneralClassName>`, while the key is the variabile Name.

In other words I'd like to sum Number grouping by Name.

Now, the only thing that came across my mind is a nested foreach, something like that:

```
Dictionary<string, int> resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(List<OtherClass> listOtherClass in bigListGeneralClass.Select(x => x.SpecificList))
{
    foreach(OtherClass otherClass in listOtherClass)
    {
        int value = 0;
        if(resultDictionary.ContainsKey(otherClass.Name))
        {
            resultDictionary[otherClass.Name] += otherClass.Number;
        }
        else
        {
            resultDictionary.Add(otherClass.Name, otherClass.Number);
        }
    }
}
```

While this solution seems to work well, I don't like it at all.
Is there a more clean way to find this result? Maybe through a nice LINQ query?

Comment: What is the otherClass.count? Did you mean otherClass.Number ?

Comment: I used a different variable name when I first write the question. Then while reading the text I find the use of "count" confusing. The one you found must be slipped :| sorry for the mistake & thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you don't use any information from the `GeneralClassName` you can use `SelectMany` to flatten your list. This flat list of `OtherClass` instances is than grouped by the `Name` property. Finally, the list of groups is transformed into a dictionary with the key of the group (aka the `Name` property) being the key of the new property and the value being the sum of all `Number` values in that group:

```
var result = bigListGeneralClass.SelectMany(x => x.SpecificList)
                                .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                                              x => x.Sum(y => y.Number));
```

This code assumes that `OtherClass.Number` is in fact an `int` not a `string`. This assumption is also used in your sample code with the loop.
If this assumption is not correct, change `y.Number` to `int.Parse(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, y.Number)`.
Note: This will throw an exception if any of the numbers can't be parsed, so you might want to make sure beforehand that all contain valid numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> result =
            bigListGeneralClass.SpecificList.GroupBy(sl => sl.Name)
                                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Number)));
```

Comment: This doesn't work as `List<GeneralClassName>` doesn't have a member `SpecificList`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth bigListGeneralClass isn't list of GeneralClassName, it's just object of type GeneralClassName.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Sorry, I was careless. 

`bigListGeneralClass.SelectMany(l => l.SpecificList).GroupBy(sl => sl.Name)
                                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Number)));`

That's corrected version.

Comment: And that's what I posted nearly an hour ago ;-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth , Oh, no... There are mistake in your snippet ;) Number is string but you used it as int :)
OK. I marked your answer as useful. :)

Comment: I wrote a whole paragraph about int vs string below the code. But you are right, I missed that at first.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Ok, thаnks for discussion. I find the SelectMany extension as very useful, and i use it often.

Comment: I agree, SelectMany is very useful. As you can see, I am using it, too.